# How to set parameters for CUDAFunctionLoad for a CUDA kernel?

Tags: cudalink

I am trying to load the following CUDA kernel using `CUDAFunctionLoad`:

```cpp
__device__ float atomicMaxf(float* address, float val){
    int *address_as_int =(int*)address;
    int old = *address_as_int, assumed;
    while (val > __int_as_float(old)) {
       assumed = old;
       old = atomicCAS(address_as_int, assumed,
                    __float_as_int(val));
    }
    return __int_as_float(old);
}

__global__ void max_reduce(const float* const d_array, float* d_max, 
                                          const size_t elements){
extern __shared__ float shared[];

int tid = threadIdx.x;
int gid = (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x) + tid;
shared[tid] = -FLOAT_MAX;  // 1

if (gid < elements)
    shared[tid] = d_array[gid];
__syncthreads();

for (unsigned int s=blockDim.x/2; s>0; s>>=1) {
    if (tid < s && gid < elements)
        shared[tid] = max(shared[tid], shared[tid + s]);  // 2
    __syncthreads();
}
// what to do now?
// option 1: save block result and launch another kernel
if (tid == 0)        
    d_max[blockIdx.x] = shared[tid]; // 3
// option 2: use atomics
if (tid == 0)
  atomicMaxf(d_max, shared[0]);
}
```

The above code is copied to a string called `findPeaksKernelCode`.

How do I define the parameter set in the `CUDAFunctionLoad`?

```
findPeaksKernel = 
  CUDAFunctionLoad[findPeaksKernelCode, "findPeaksKernel", {{"Float"},{"Float"}}, 16]
```

does not work.

Comment: I cannot help you because I don't have any CUDA-compatible GPU, but I'd like to say that "does not work" work is a very inprecise problem description. Are there any error messages?